# Highlighting a home made langage in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to define special lexer for highlighting file using a personal langage, a DSL ?

Any clue is welcome and if this need to play with Python, this is not a problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a nice tutorial that should get you started: [official doc about highlighting](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/sublime-text-2/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html?highlight=highlight).